# tensorflow MNIST fully_connected_feed.py fails: range() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having trouble running the example in one of the [tensor flow tutorials](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.md). The tutorial says to run I just need to type `python fully_connected_feed.py`. When I do this it gets through fetching the input data, but then fails, like so:

```py
Extracting data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 225, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 11, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 221, in main
    run_training()
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 141, in run_training
    loss = mnist.loss(logits, labels_placeholder)
  File "/Users/me/tftmp/mnist.py", line 96, in loss
    indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(batch_size), 1)
TypeError: range() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I *think* this error is caused because there is some problem with session setup and/or tensor evaluation. This is the function in mnist.py causing the problem:

```py
def loss(logits, labels):
  """Calculates the loss from the logits and the labels.

  Args:
    logits: Logits tensor, float - [batch_size, NUM_CLASSES].
    labels: Labels tensor, int32 - [batch_size].

  Returns:
    loss: Loss tensor of type float.
  """
  # Convert from sparse integer labels in the range [0, NUM_CLASSSES)
  # to 1-hot dense float vectors (that is we will have batch_size vectors,
  # each with NUM_CLASSES values, all of which are 0.0 except there will
  # be a 1.0 in the entry corresponding to the label).
  batch_size = tf.size(labels)
  labels = tf.expand_dims(labels, 1)
  indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(batch_size), 1)
  concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, labels])
  onehot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(
      concated, tf.pack([batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]), 1.0, 0.0)
  cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, onehot_labels,
                                                          name='xentropy')
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
  return loss
```

If I put all the code in the `loss` function inside a `with tf.Session():` block, it gets past this error. However, I get other errors later about uninitialised variables, so I'm guessing something major is going wrong with session setup or initialisation, or something. Being new to tensor flow I'm a little at a loss. Any ideas?

[NB: I havent edited the code at all, just downloaded from the tensorflow tutorials and tried to run as instructed, with `python fully_connected_feed.py`]

Comment: See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/194

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue arises because in the latest version of the TensorFlow source on GitHub, `tf.range()` has been [updated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/6b12d081d54b89869e26d9d99828f13de381761e#diff-f0675f2568ff9470bcfc1f2bc79c5386L539) to be more permissive with its arguments (previously it required two arguments; now it has the same semantics as Python's `range()` built-in function), and the `fully_connected_feed.py` example has been updated to exploit this.

However, if you try to run this version against the binary distribution of TensorFlow, you will get this error because the change to `tf.range()` has not been incorporated into the binary package.

The easiest solution is to download [the old version of `mnist.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/1d76583411038767f673a0c96174c80eaf9ff42f/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py). Alternatively, you could [build from source](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#installing_from_sources) to use the latest version of the tutorial.

Comment: Great, replaced just the single call to tf.range in mnist.py and runs fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can right result fix mnist code like this :

```
indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0,batch_size),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: range() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

That's the error.

Looking at the [tensorflow docs for range](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/constant_op.md#range), we can see that `range` has a function signature of `start, limit, delta=1, name='range'`. This means that at least two arguments are required for function invocation. Your example only shows one argument provided.

An example can be found in the docs:

```
# 'start' is 3
# 'limit' is 18
# 'delta' is 3
tf.range(start, limit, delta) ==> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```